# Do ExpressCheckout Payment 呼び出し時のエラーについて

Tags: paypal

カード決済エラー（エラーコード10486）発生時の挙動をテストをするために、Sandboxで10486を意図的に出すテストアカウントを作成することは可能でしょうか。（Balanceをゼロにしたバイヤーアカウントだと決済が通ってしまう）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandboxで支払い者のPayPalアカウントにてクレジットカードに紐付いている住所の【番地】に【CCREJECT-REFUSED】を設定しておき、決済テスト時にその支払い者のPayPalアカウントで支払いをすると、DoExpressCheckoutPayment APIにて10486のエラーが返ってくるようになります。

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/#testing

Comment: 再現しました。解答ありがとうございます！